# How to convert year and month to RFC 3339 formatting in php

Tags: php

I have date like 2017 December. How can I convert it to a  RFC 3339 formatting? I have got no clue whatsoever! 
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solved it like this

```
$date='2017 December';
echo date("c", strtotime($date));
```